# Asymptotic running time of algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

Given the following algorithm of multiplying matrices which are all n x n

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){
       s=0;       
       for(int k=1;k<=n;k++){
          s+=A[i][k]*B[k][j];
          C[i][j]=s;
       }
    }
}
return s;
```

The asymptotic running time is Theta(n^3) ,however what does this mean :

> If we consider the running time  as a function of the length of the input the order growth is Theta( m ^(3/2) ) where m is the length of the input i.e m is the order of the number elements in the matrices  and m = Theta(n^2)

Why the growth of the input is Theta( m ^(3/2) ) and Is the whole asymptotic running time Theta(n^2)?

Comment: There are `m = n*n` elements in an `n x n` matrix. So, if the algorithm is `Ɵ(m^(3/2))`, then it's `Ɵ(n^2^(3/2)) = Ɵ(n^3)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner, that's a good explanation. I think the same.

Answer (score 0):

If we have asymptotic time T is :
T = Theta(n^3)
this mean, that our time is in proportion to this t :
t = k*(n^3)
we also have m is order of magnitud of number of elements :
m = Theta(n^2).
This mean, that m' , a specific number of elements is something like :
m' = g*(n^2)
(g and k are constants)
If we put n in function of m' :
n = (m'/g)^(1/2)
We substitute this :
t = k*(n^3) = k*(m'/g)^(3/2) ///// 
t = (k/(g^(3/2)) * (m'^(3/2))
left part is constant
so
T = Theta(m^(3/2))
greatings, Daniel